# QField doesn't show the antenna height compensation

Tags: qfield

QField doesn't show any difference in the height of 1 points. With or without the antenna height compensation. I'm using the emlid RX.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.